# Bootstrap carousel in RoR not working

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I am adding bootstrap carousel in my RoR application but the carousel doesn't seem to be working. After consulting from stackoverflow, some suggested using `$('#myCarousel').carousel()` but it doesn't do the trick. My application goes to link `localhost:3000/#carousel-example-captions` without the slide of carousel.

My carousel code is as follows:

```
<div id="carousel-example-captions" class="carousel slide">
<!-- Indicators -->
<ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-captions" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-captions" data-slide-to="1"></li>
</ol>
<!-- Wrapper for slides -->
<div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="item active">
        <img src="http://i.imm.io/1g9kc.png" alt="..." />
        <div class="carousel-caption">aaaaa</div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <img src="http://i.imm.io/1g9kF.png" alt="..." />
        <div class="carousel-caption">gggggg</div>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- Controls -->
<a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-captions" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="icon-prev"></span>
</a>
<a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-captions" data-slide="next">
    <span class="icon-next"></span>
</a>
```

UPDATE: I am not sure if I am writing `$('#id').carousel()` at right place. I have tried adding the following code at application.js, home.js.coffee, right after the carousel view in a `<script>` tag (I am a newbie in RoR, so I can't be sure about the conventions):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#carousel-example-captions').carousel();
});
```

Comment: Is the ID of the wrapper #myCarousel? From what I see you should call: `$(".carousel").carousel();`

Comment: Not working for both `#myCarousel` & `.carousel`. And, yes, `#myCarousel` is the ID.

Comment: Do you get any other JS error? If you are using Chrome, press F12 and check your Console tab. Please paste them if any.

Comment: I am getting a JQuery error: `event.returnValue is deprecated. Please use the standard event.preventDefault() instead.` and I am using `gem 'jquery-rails', '~> 3.0.0'`

Answer (score 0):

You are not using the "default" id for your carousel, thus you would have to use that ID to initialize it...

```
$(".carousel-example-generic").carousel()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can fire up carousel functionality with `data-ride="carousel"` attribute in your carousel wrapper. Your first line will look like:

```
<div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
```

Not sure if it's a error, but in the code you have pasted, you need to close `div` tag in the last line.

Comment: `data-ride` didn't help. On the `<div>` tag closing part, I have included it in the original code. I am just doing hit and trail. The lack of RoR knowledge is really taking my toll.

Comment: oh ok. Please paste your `application.js`

Comment: `//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require twitter/bootstrap
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree `

Comment: @EduLomeli..I got it working now. I didn't include the `carousel.js` and `transition.js` in my application. Thanks for the direction. If you can edit your answer then I can mark is as correct.